# I have installed java free chart.How can I now use the java free chart to plot smooth curves in java

Tags: java

Can anyone help me in using java *free chart library* to plot graphs in java? I have `Jfree chart* downloaded in my laptop. I dont know how to use the code from *java free Chart*. Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer one of the links below to understand how to use jFreeChart in your java application.

- [JFreeChart - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JFreeChart/article.html)
- [Chart a new course with JFreeChart](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074798/build-ci-sdlc/chart-a-new-course-with-jfreechart.html)
- [JFree Chart Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jfreechart/)